# MPI_Wait: Internal MPI error, what could have cause this in my cluster?

Tags: mpi

I am using cluster to run a job. In my mpi launch command, I used -IBV (not -ibv) option, which I think is to make it uses the Infiniband.

But some of the job will end up self-killed with error messages in the stderr as follow (a long list of identical message, so I just copy one for each type):

> ls-dyna_R9.2.0_s: Rank 0:11: MPI_Isend: 722 dereg_trypin failed: id
>   0x0, 0x7f0742de7694,1150916
>
> ls-dyna_R9.2.0_s: Rank 0:11: MPI_Recv: 722 dereg_trypin failed: id
>   0x0, 0x7f0742de7694,1150916
>
> ls-dyna_R9.2.0_s: Rank 0:11: MPI_Wait: 722 dereg_trypin failed: id
>   0x0, 0x7f0742de7694,1150916
>
> and then finally it ends with:
>
> ls-dyna_R9.2.0_s: Rank 0:11: MPI_Wait: 722 dereg_trypin failed: id
>   0x0, 0x7f0742de7694,1150916
>
> ls-dyna_R9.2.0_s: Rank 0:11: MPI_Wait: ln1313: ibv_reg_mr() failed:
>   addr 0x7f0742de7694, len 1150916
>
> ls-dyna_R9.2.0_s: Rank 0:11: MPI_Wait: Internal MPI error

If I use option -TCP (not -tcp), this will not occur for the same job.
I want to solve the problem, but I do not understand the error message, nor do  I know what is wrong with the MPI.
Can anyone provide some advises?

Comment: which MPI are you using ? LSDyna is a commercial product, and you might hence consider asking them directly since you pay for that.

Comment: I am using IBM platform MPI  9.01.04.03.
I did ask LS-DYNA. After numerous trial, I eventually come to the conclusion this is my in house submission script (using mpi) fault and I need to fix it first.

Comment: and did you contact IBM ? iirc, platform MPI is a commercial product too.

Comment: I didn't contact IBM. According to my IT person, this is a free software.